# error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'const signed char*'

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

```
uint8_t* buf1;
...
const signed char* buf2 = static_cast<const signed char*>(buf1);
```

> invalid static_cast from type 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' to type
>   'const signed char*'

c-style-cast: (const signed char*) works fine

Is there any danger using c-style-cast vs static_cast in this case?

Comment: Well, define *"danger"*. It *is* legal.

Comment: static_cast error is suggesting this is not safe operation, why static_cast is failing?

Comment: because you need `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: No `static_cast` is telling you it can't cast it, not that it's dangerous to cast it, you'd need to use `reinterpret_cast` here, it fails because signed and unsigned chars are different types

Comment: Because `static_cast` cannot cast between pointers to different types (`void*` aside). You can use `reinterpret_cast` for that. Whether the operation is safe depends on where the input came from and what you are doing with it. From the language point of view, it is certainly legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any danger using c-style-cast vs static_cast in this case?

static_cast is not an option in this case at all, as the error message explains.

The danger of using c-style cast is that you may not have intended to perform a reinterpret_cast, which is what c-style cast performs here. If you intend to perform a reinterpret_cast, then use reinterpret_cast. If you intend to use static_cast, then your logic is wrong, because the types are incompatible with static_cast.